# ASP.NET URL rewrites based on membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, url-rewriting, asp.net-membership

It's been quite a few years since I've been involved with .NET or ASP. I got thrown into a project to help reach a looming deadline.

The project is upgrading a web app to a new version. My duty is to figure out a way of redirecting the user to whichever version they are supposed to be using. We don't want to modify the old version at all so I'm attempting to do this in the new version.

Version 2 sits at www.example.com while version 1 sits at www.example.com:8080. I created a field in the company table to determine which version the company should be using. We are using Forms Based Authentication with Roles.

We have both versions running on IIS 7 on Windows 2008. Version 1 is .NET 1 and Version 2 is .NET 2.5.

Topology:
Windows Server 2008
IIS 7
Default Website
 - WebAppV1
 - WebAppV2

Since frames are heavily implemented, Response.Redirect doesn't work. I need to rewrite the URL itself. I would also like to be able to submit and login the user automatically with the same username and password entered into the version 2 auth form.

Could someone tell me which of these are my best course of action?

1. Create a blank page with javascript that redirects the user and Response.Redirect to it. This one doesn't allow me to submit the form information though.
2. Create an URL Rewrite rule in IIS 7 based on membership roles. I still don't know if that's possible, but haven't found a way to do it yet. Still can't figure out how to implement the user form.
3. Find some magic url rewrite trick in one of the functions in Global.asax. I haven't been successful with this one so far, but wanted to know if I just needed to dig deeper before wasting time with it. I think I ran across some code that would do the form submission, but can't rewrite the url that I can see.

Comment: Does this relate to Classic ASP? It's a different problem if you have to rewrite URLs for both. Also, which versions? IIS? .NET? Windows?

Comment: @JohnSaunders This is ASP .NET with C# behind it. Version 1 is in .NET 1 and we are writing the new app for .NET 2.5. We have both apps running in IIS 7 on Windows 2008.

Comment: @BryanF. - asp.net 1 is not "asp-classic", that's pre-asp.net asp (that is, asp without the .net)

Comment: What's your topology? Will they always be running under one IIS7 instance?

Comment: @MystereMan sorry. didn't realize it put it in there. Removed.

Comment: @MichaelKrauklis Yes they will until version 1 is phased out.

Comment: There is no .NET 2.5. Do you mean 3.5?